# How to get product description from Aliexpress with API?

Tags: python, api, e-commerce, aliexpress

I was scraping product details with beautifulsoup from aliexpress. But that is too slow and too much of a hassle.

So I signed up for the aliexpress API. Everything works. **But how can I get the description of products using the API?**

I found nothing in the help center. Google also does not have anything. I am also using

https://github.com/EitherSoft/python-aliexpress-api-client

It seems to me that it is not possible to get the description with the API? The documentation for the API is very poor imo.

---

Right now I am using this call:
http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/MY_API_KEY?fields=imageUrl,productId&keywords=chess&highQualityItems=yes
This call only returns the image, product id for products with the keyword "chess".
But how can I also get the description?

Comment: The `Get product details:` doesn't fit you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not quite know what you mean? Right now I am using this call: http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/MY_API_KEY?fields=imageUrl,productId&keywords=chess&highQualityItems=yes This call only returns the image, product id for products with the keyword "chess". But how can I also get the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Comment**: how can I get the description?

The API provide the following details, there is no `description`.
I assume you have to get it from the `productUrl`.

> [config.py](https://github.com/EitherSoft/python-aliexpress-api-client/blob/master/aliexpress_api_client/config.py)
>     'details': [
>           'productId',
>           'productTitle',
>           'productUrl',
>           'imageUrl',
>           'originalPrice',
>           'salePrice',
>           'discount',
>           'evaluateScore',
>           'commission',
>           'commissionRate',
>           '30daysCommission',
>           'volume',
>           'packageType',
>           'lotNum',
>           'validTime',
>           'storeName',
>           'storeUrl',
>           'allImageUrls',

---

> **Question**: . I do not quite know what you mean?

What do you get using the following:

```
from aliexpress_api_client import AliExpress
aliexpress = AliExpress('api_key', 'affiliate_id')

#Get product details:
product = aliexpress.get_product_details(['productId', 'productTitle', 'salePrice'], product_id)
print(product)
```

Comment: It returns a dictionary with the product id, the title and the price. But how can I get the description?

Comment: I will then scrape the description from the URL.Do you maybe know how I can get the "product-ids" for the variations?

Comment: @Wramana: Didn't you get this using `&keywords=chess`? Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a node.js package then, I have written a **scraper** and made it available as an npm package. This would give you complete information about the product as `JSON` response. You would receive feedbacks, product images, description, product info including stock details etc.,

https://github.com/sudheer-ranga/aliexpress-product-scraper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aliexpress-product-scraper

Install the npm package
`npm i aliexpress-product-scraper`

Get product details:

```
const scrape = require('aliexpress-product-scraper');
const product = scrape('32958933105');

product.then(res => {
  console.log('Product Details JSON: ', res);
});
```